# Using AngularJS with Github Pages

Tags: angularjs, github-pages

I am not able to render the Angular on my webpage correctly when using Github Pages.

Problem page: http://weblue.github.io/

I thought this original to be a conflict with Jeckyll, so I changed the symbols for parsing to {( )} to avoid a conflict.

The page still only displays {(variable)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will notice that you links to the .js files are linked to `../TierlistTemplate/js/..` but in reality they are in `/js/..` so you will have to fix that.